# momentJS: floating point days for durations?

Tags: momentjs

I'm seeing some surprising behavior adding a duration to a moment:

```
var moment = require('moment');
var now = new moment();
var halfday = moment.duration(1/2, 'd');
var fullday = moment.duration(1, 'd');
var day_ago = now.clone().subtract(fullday);
var halfday_ago = now.clone().subtract(halfday);
var otherhalf_ago = now.clone().subtract(halfday.as('ms'));
if (day_ago.isSame(halfday_ago)) { console.log("surprise!"); }
if (!halfday_ago.isSame(otherhalf_ago)) { console.log("surprise!"); }
```

examining the actual dates, subtracting halfday subtracts a full day (and adding halfday adds nothing). doing the computation with halfday.as('ms') produces the correct result. The momentjs code is pretty opaque in this regard, is this expected behavior?

Comment: Yes, it's not stated explicitly in the docs, but anytime you specify a number and a unit (like `5, 'days'`) the unit is expected to be an integer. This is likely because units like `months` and `years` can't really be fractional without moment having to guess exactly what you mean.

Comment: yes, looking at their test suite, it's all integer all the time. what a surprising thing to leave out of the docs! 

floats are very convenient for math with durations, and the result is well-defined for non-calendar units (non month or year). wrapping their duration constructor to "unbubble" seems like a decent way forward.

Comment: Yeah, you have a point. I'd stick to doing everything in ms or whatever your smallest increment is. You can do `var halfday = moment.duration(moment.duration(1,'d').asMilliseconds()/2)`. Not ideal though.