# Why doesn't moment.js year diff year not match exactly 1?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I have executed these simple JS code lines

```
moment.duration(moment(new Date(2013,1,1)).diff(moment(new Date(2012,1,1)))).asYears()
moment.duration(moment(new Date(2012,1,1)).diff(moment(new Date(2011,1,1)))).asYears()
moment.duration(moment(new Date(2011,1,1)).diff(moment(new Date(2010,1,1)))).asYears()
moment.duration(moment(new Date(2010,1,1)).diff(moment(new Date(2009,1,1)))).asYears()
```

Outputs

```
1.0020739645577939
0.9993360575508053
0.9993360575508053
0.9993360575508053
```

Surely, there must be something wrong?

OR perhaps this anomaly  has something to do with leap years? 2012 was a leap year

So I tried the next leap year 2016

```
moment.duration(moment(new Date(2016,1,1)).diff(moment(new Date(2015,1,1)))).asYears()
```

which outputs same as previous non leap years, so maybe has nothing to do with it

```
0.9993360575508053
```

Anyone has any idea what is going on?

Comment: [Possibly related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29442583/momentjs-floating-point-days-for-durations)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, note that `new Date(year,1,1)` refers to *February* 1st, not January. Javascript, following the UNIX time_t convention, numbers months starting with 0, with the idea being that you'll use the month number to index into an array of month names instead of using it directly. So to construct a Date object referring to January 1st, you should call `new Date(year,0,1)`.

Second, taking a difference that's a whole number of days and converting to years will never result in a a whole number. You should instead ask Moment to give the difference in years in the first place:

```
> moment(new Date(2013,0,1)).diff(moment(new Date(2012,0,1)),'year');
1
```

If you want the result to include fractions of a year instead of being truncated to a whole number, add a truthy third parameter to `diff`. Here we're counting from July to January:

```
> moment(new Date(2013,0,1)).diff(moment(new Date(2012,6,1)),'year',true)
0.5
```

Your method doesn't work because a calendar year is not a fixed number of seconds; it's either 365 days, which is 31,536,000 seconds, or 366 days, which is 31,622,400 seconds. Since leap years usually happen every four years, the *average* calendar year is 365.25 days, or 31,557,600 seconds; and in fact, a light-year is defined as the the distance light travels in that exact number of seconds.

But in the modern Gregorian calendar, the leap-century rules mean that the average length of a year, which you have to take over 400 years to get a complete cycle, is really a little shorter: 365.2425 days or 31,556,952 seconds. This is the value Moment uses, but it only works as an average; any anniversaries that aren't an exact multiple of 400 years will never give you an integer result. Instead, as you found out,  a common year will count as 31,536,000 / 31,556,952 = 0.99933605755085028689843... of a year, while a leap year will count as 31,622,400 / 31,556,952 = 1.00207396455779379453376886... years.

In your last example you got the common year value because you were asking for the length of the year from 2015 to 2016 - which is the length of the year 2015. If you count from 2016 to 2017, you get the expected leap year value:

```
> moment.duration(moment(new Date(2017,0,1)).diff(moment(new Date(2016,0,1)))).asYears()
1.0020739645577939
```

More specifically, you get the leap year length whenever the interval includes a Feb 29th. So if you're measuring the delta between the same date in consecutive years, you'll get 366 days if you start on any date between March 1st of the year before a leap year and February 28th of the leap year itself. If you start counting from February 29th, then of course there is no February 29th in the following year; you'll get 365 days if you count to February 28th and 366 if you count to March 1st. Starting with March 1st in the leap year the time to the recurrence of the same date is back to 365 days:

```
> moment.duration(moment(new Date(2016,1,28)).diff(moment(new Date(2015,1,28)))).asYears()
0.9993360575508053
> moment.duration(moment(new Date(2016,2,1)).diff(moment(new Date(2015,2,1)))).asYears()
1.0020739645577939
> moment.duration(moment(new Date(2017,1,28)).diff(moment(new Date(2016,1,28)))).asYears()
1.0020739645577939
> moment.duration(moment(new Date(2017,2,1)).diff(moment(new Date(2016,2,1)))).asYears()
0.9993360575508053
```

Comment: Great answer. This works great. However i was expecting something like
moment(new Date(2013,1,1)).diff(moment(new Date(2012,6,1)),'year');
to return 0.5, but it returns 0

Comment: Figured it out. I just need to add in a true as an extra parameter after 'year'

Comment: Thanks for that, @Daniel; I've incorporated it into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
moment(new Date(2013,1,1)).diff(moment(new Date(2012,1,1)),'year');
```